# What would need to change if structural typing was added to c#?

Tags: c#, language-design, type-systems, structural-typing

In a similar vein to the blog post by Eric on [non nullable reference types](http://blog.coverity.com/2013/11/20/c-non-nullable-reference-types), where the solution to the problem seems trivial, but its clearly not.

Why couldn't structural typing be added to c#? What problems would arise if something like the (bad) example below was just dropped into the language?

```
public structural interface INode
{
 INode Next {get;}
}

class MyLinkedNode { ... } // structurally implements INode
class GraphNode { ... } // this also structurally implements INode

int CountNodes(INode start) 
{
  int i = 0;
  for (INode current = start; current != null; current = current.Next)
   i++;

  return i;
};

void GetCounts()
{
  MyLinedNode node1 = BuildLinkedNodes();
  GraphNode node2 = BuildGraphNodes();

  int count1 = CountNodes(node1);
  int count2 = CountNodes(node2);

  int count3 = CountNodes("hello world"); // compile fail, as string type structure invalid
}
```

Comment: Not entirely sure how your example demonstrates structural typing.. other than the `structural` keyword you've added..

Comment: OK, you've added some usage, but hey, you can do exactly the same thing without `structural` keyword!

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek depends on what your talking about. I added the `structural` keyword just to distinguish it from a regular interface.

Comment: I suppose the C# team figured you could simply inherit the interface explicitly, or use generics.

Comment: This isn't just a C# thing.. its a CLR thing. The entire type system would need an overhaul to support it.

Comment: @RobertHarvey great when you have control of all the source, not so great if you don't. You're now forced to wrap / create adapters for these types.

Comment: Ah, now you're making sense, although most sensible libraries expose the appropriate interfaces anyway.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead does f# not have a form of structural typing?

Comment: @SimonWhitehead could you explain some of the changes the type system would need to support this please? I'm happy to mark that as the answer. I'm curious to what impact it would have.

Comment: @jasper I mean that, in order for the CLR to verify the state of the stack at any given time.. it would need to have structural typing baked into the core - in order to keep its guarantee of type safety.

Comment: @Simon: Verification is actually *not* a reason that C# would need help from the CLR.  C++/CLI templates, F# static type parameters, and C# `dynamic` all manage this operation without any help from the CLR.   CLR support *would* be needed to allow runtime specialization to new actual values of the type parameters.

Comment: @BenVoigt I get your point now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would lose all the advantages of dynamic polymorphism which are provided by virtual calls and generics.

In the current version of C#, `CountNodes` (and a hypothetical generic version `CountNodes<T> where T : INode`) is compiled as a single function, where the access to the `Next` property has fixed, at compile time, the offset into the v-table of the object which must be used to find the property getter.  As a result, new types deriving from `INode` and defined in other assemblies can be supplied to `CountNodes`, since they conform to the same v-table layout.

Since the v-table layout is different between `MyGraphNode` and `MyLinkedNode` (they are defined without awareness of any required layout), this approach cannot work.  The compiler would have to generate new and different code for each actual parameter type.  This would limit you to types which existed at compile time and were known at the call site.  For example, this would work:

```
GraphNode node = BuildGraphNodes();
int count = CountNodes(node);
```

but this would not:

```
object node = BuildGraphNodes();
int count = CountNodes(node);
```

Actually, this capability has already been developed.  It is called C++ templates.  And Microsoft provides a C++/CLI compiler that allows you to use it with .NET.  It is even more powerful than the "structural interfaces" you proposed, but it easily accommodates your use case.

```
template<typename INode>
int CountNodes(INode^ start) 
{
    int i = 0;
    for (INode^ current = start; current != nullptr; current = current->Next)
        ++i;

    return i;
}
```

(C++/CLI works within the confines of the CLR, and does not require DLR support, quite contrary to what some commenters claimed.)

Given that this ability is already accessible to .NET developers, and would add considerable additional complexity to C#, it is unlikely to pass the cost-benefit analysis of the C# designers.  So don't expect C++ templates, or even the lesser "structural interfacing", to ever be part of C#.

If you're willing to forgo all benefits of static type checking, you can use late (lookup by name, not v-table slot) binding in C# today.  Just change the parameter type to `dynamic`.  But errors will be delayed until runtime, and performance will also take a significant hit.

Comment: I'm still confused as to how C++ templates fit the requirements here. Maybe its just still too early for me.

Comment: @Simon: C++ templates use duck typing / structural interfaces.  Or are you asking why I consider C++ templates available via C++/CLI to be a viable (although not zero-effort) alternative to support inside C#?

Comment: ok, that's quite interesting in regard to the v-table. Thanks. I can see the issues in regard to that. 
`dynamic`.. ugh :) Its the compile time checking I'd like to see added.

Comment: @BenVoigt Your edit makes it clear.. and is what I was getting confused with. I am aware that vanilla C++ compiles a new class/method - per-template.. I assume this is also the case in C++/CLI. I understand what you mean now.

Comment: @Simon: Yes.  C++/CLI supports both templates and generics, with different sets of semantics (one is completely specialized at compile-time like native C++, the other is compiled to vtable slot indexes during compilation, making it JIT-compatible with new types like C#)

Comment: Awesome. That makes sense.. now I understand your statement. Cheers.

Comment: @jasper: You could actually do this using Reflection, which supports runtime codegen, and avoid (except the first pass) the runtime penalty of dynamic.

Comment: Aren't C++ templates just a form of generics, but implemented at compile-time?

Comment: @Robert: If you are using "generic" in the broad CS sense, yes.  But it seems you mean ".NET generics".  Then no, not even close, compile-time instantiation by itself wouldn't be enough for metaprogramming.  Generics cannot be specialized, templates can.  Generics do not support non-type parameters, templates do.  Conversely generics allow (require, really) constraints, templates are duck typed.  Generics give good error messages, template error messages are renowned for their length and indecipherability.

Answer (score 2):

> Why couldn't structural typing be added to c#?

In general, this would be possible.  It would require a completely different form of resolution to be added to the C# language compared to what currently exists.

> What problems would arise if something like the (bad) example below was just dropped into the language?

There would be a new set of rules required, as well as an entire different means of overload in the compiler.

That being said, this is definitely possible.  F# (today) supports a form of this via [statically resolved type parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd548046.aspx), and compiles to the same IL as C#.  C++/CLI also supports this type of operation via templates, which also are resolved and handled at compile time.

You can accomplish something similar to this in C# today via `dynamic`, though you lose all compile time checking.